# CSS control of foreground and background

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two separate conditions that control foreground color and background color of a text box. The conditions are totally separate. One condition controls foreground and the other controls background. I am setting the class in JavaScript and I'm lost as to how to set the class.

Do I have a CSS element for each possibility of foreground/ background mix or is it possible to have multiple classes?

Comment: Can you add your CSS and JS code please.

Comment: You can have multiple classes on an element and here is some information on how to add/remove classes with pure JavaScript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS**

```
.backgroundToggled {
}

.foregroundToggled {
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id='myId'></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var element = document.getElementById('myId');
if( /* condition foreground */) { 
   element.className += ' foregroundToggled';
}  
if( /* condition bacground */) { 
   element.className += ' backgroundToggled';
}
```

**or Jquery:**

```
if( /* condition foreground */) { 
   $('myId').addClass('foregroundToggled');
}  
if( /* condition bacground */) { 
   $('myId').addClass('backroundToggled');
}
```

If condition foreground && condition background are true, your div will be:

```
<div id='myId' class='foregroundToggled backroundToggled'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have multiple classes.

css:

```
.class1{
    background-color: blue;
}
.class2{
    color: red;
}
```

html

```
<div class="class1 class2"></div>
```